# Determine if a reflected property can be assigned a given value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

What is the easiest way to determine if a reflected property can be assigned a given value ?

The method signature of what I need is :

```
public static bool IsAssignable(PropertyInfo property, object value)
{        
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This method should work for value type and reference type and weither value is null or not.

Thanks for you help guys.

Manitra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stefan's and John responses, and the "Determine if a reflected property can be assigned null" question, here is the code I'll use :

```
public static bool IsAssignable(PropertyInfo property, object value)
{
    if (value == null && property.PropertyType.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) == null)
        return false;
    if (value != null && !property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

This works for all cases and in a pure loosely typed fashion.

Manitra.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But if the value is null and I can't can't call GetType() on it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't determine the type of `null` which is passed as `object`. You only can say if the property is able to take `null` at all.

You could take the compile-time type for that reason:

```
public static bool IsAssignable<T>(PropertyInfo property, T value)
{        
    if (value != null)
    {
        return property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType());
    }
    return property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's correct in a strongly typed use case (upvoted). In my case, I really have an object as value so I can't use typeof(T). But, actually, I found a similar question which deals with a null value so it's ok.